# How to use X-Content-Type-Options for .css and .png file?

Tags: php, apache2

I have this code in my initialization file.

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';
        connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';");
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block");
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

This code works but my problem is, it is only working in the document (localhost), in the `.css` and `.png` files are not working.

Here are the screenshots:

**Document (localhost)**

[image]

**.css file**

[image]

**.png file**

[image]

How can I make header response to the `.css` and `.png` files? `dareboost` gave me this note:

> **Disable the auto detection of resource type**
>
> Protect yourself from
>   malicious exploitation via MIME sniffing.
>
> MIME-Type sniffing explained
>
> Internet Explorer and Chrome browsers have a feature called "MIME-Type
>   sniffing" that automatically detects a web resource's type. This
>   means, for example, that a resource identified as an image can be read
>   as a script if its content is a script.
>
> This property allows a malicious person to send a file to your website
>   to inject malicious code. We advise you to disable the MIME-Type
>   sniffing to limit such activity.
>
> How to prevent MIME-Type sniffing
>
> Configure a "X-Content-Type-Options" HTTP header. Add the
>   "X-Content-Type-Options" HTTP header in the responses of each
>   resource, associated to the "nosniff" value. It allows you to guard
>   against such misinterpretations of your resources.
>
> On this page, you should configure the following resources, that risk
>   being misinterpreted:
>
> `http://www.example.com/path/style.css`
>   `http://www.example.com/path/logo.png`
>   `http://www.example.com/path/icon.png`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set these HTTP response headers in your server config (or `.htaccess` file). For example, to apply the `X-Content-Type-Options` HTTP response header only to `.css` and `.png` files, try the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|png)$">
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in PHP? and the code is giving me an `internal server error 500`.

Comment: Now the `.css` file is working but `.png` file is not.

Comment: It is working now.

Comment: Regarding the "error 500" - sorry, I missed the slash on the closing `</FilesMatch>` (I guess you must have fixed that). If it wasn't working, but now it is - you may have had a local caching issue. And no, you can't do this with PHP (or rather, you really really shouldn't... you would need to write a PHP script through which you passed all your static resources... a lot more work and hopelessly inefficient for something like this.)